# android dialog transparent

Tags: android

I want to get rid of the border in my dialog box and make it look absolutly transparent, as if the image is on the top of screen.

[image]

My dialog xml is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dialog with transparent background in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try below code

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Comment: Now a new problem has comeup. the entire screen flickers as described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379322/android-fullscreen-status-bar-flickers
I was wondering if there is any workaround or if i can get the same effect without using the dialog?

Comment: Tried that and still getting this issue. I made my Activity to go full screen as well thinking that it might work but it didn't/

Comment: I dont know if that works or will create the same problem try using Activity instead Dialog

Comment: Turn the animation of activity off and set the theme transparent in xml it will work as Dialog

Comment: And in the manifest this can be added to the activity's declaration:  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" and  android:layout_gravity="center"   - to the xml layout.

Answer (score 63):

try this:

```
mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

Comment: is there anyway to change a dialog to 50% opacity without changing its background?

Comment: The only problem about this solution is that it will not dismiss the title line on android 4+

Comment: you need to call mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) to hide the title bar.

Answer (score 20):

To give a translucent effect, say 50% opacity, use:

```
Drawable d = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);
d.setAlpha(130);
mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

'130' can be changed (0-255) to acheive desired opacity.

Comment: Or if you want a one liner, `mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x88000000));` where the "88" is a hex value that controls the transparency (00 is completely transparent, FF is completely opaque).

Answer (score 10):

try this:-

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.splash);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: for me, this works perfectly! it kees a half-transparent background and makes the dialog canceable outside the dialog content. not exactly what the question was, but for me... perfectly find :) thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

For API 11+

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this is that in your DialogFragment's onCreate() method, call

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0);
```

And if the view you returned in onCreateView does not have a background specified, the dialog's background will be just transparent.

Why? DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME means that OS will not do any drawing in the window of the dialog, and your view is 100% responsible for drawing everything about the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer causes issue with devices that have a notch, as the statusbar completely disappears and shows an ugly white background.

Instead, the right way for this is to define your own style.

```xml
<style name="FullScreenDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Now, this will make the window not have borders and be transparent over the screen.