# Transparent Alert Dialog box

Tags: android

I have few doubts regarding transparent AlertDialog box in android.I have created the alert dialog box using AlertDialog.builder in the camera surface view but i want Transparent alert dialog box is it possible. please help me

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use  [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/13/changes/android.R.style.html)
The code is as follows

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Answer taken from a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059068/android-dialog-transparent)

Comment: Note: This method only allowed on v11+ Android

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is possible.  I believe you can do it by creating a custom alert dialog:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

you can then set the background of your custom dialog to transparent like so:

```
this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.transparent);
```

(where "R.drawable.transparent" is a reference to the color "#00000000")