# Open the View as Popup in the foreground of the View

Tags: android, popup, transparent

I want to Open a Popup View on click of a Button, But the Activity behind the PopUp should be visible as the Background of the Created PopUp needs to be Transparent on demand.

Comment: I have no idea what to do!!! M searching for the Soultion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do as below

```
final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
                nagDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
                nagDialog.setCancelable(true);
                nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.temp);


                nagDialog.show();
```

where temp is your transperent layout.

Comment: Thanks xitij, Got it done by simply making the Theme Transparent in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
  "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

Answer (score 1):

My code for popup :-

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater  =     (LayoutInflater)IOStatusActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)    
final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupai, null);  

final PopupWindow popupWindowDi = new PopupWindow(popupView,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

final   TextView txtReadVal = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.lblPopUpAiReadFrmPLC);
final   EditText txtExpVal = (EditText)popupView.findViewById(R.id.txtPopUpAiExpVal);
Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnPopUpAiCancle);                          
btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
popupWindowDi.dismiss();
}});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at making a [Dialog Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) 
and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6059132/492561)