# Loading/Listener screen while data downloads from Server

Tags: android, listener

My android app is set to fetch data from a sever when it receives a notification from the server. This notification contains an ID which it uses to query the server and download data. The problem is however, if a user clicks on the notification before the data has been downloaded, there is a null pointer exception.

I'm looking for user friendly way to manage this, ideally if the user clicks on this before the data is downloaded then a loading symbol appears until it has been downloaded.

I don't have a concrete idea of doing this, are there any tutorials/example code regarding this problem? I guess I'll need to be using a listener?

Thanks!

Comment: try implementing custom listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a way:

```
 public void showProgressDialog() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mProgressDialog = onCreateProgressDialog();
                    mProgressDialog.show();
                }
            });

}

private ProgressDialog onCreateProgressDialog() {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(RequesterActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.label_dialog_item_to_find) +" "+
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_item_id)).getText().toString());
    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.label_dialog_finding_item));
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    return dialog;
}
```

Note that you could give a "no Style" to the dialog like in here [Dialog with transparent background in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android) or here [android dialog transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059068/android-dialog-transparent) depending on what you need.

I on the other hand use the `ProgressDialog` with some info in it like `"Please wait while loading item..."`. After you get the Data from the server just call the `cancel()` method for the `ProgressDialog` being showed (this `ProgressDialog` should be created in an instance variable, so you keep a track of it and could call `cancel()`from everywhere) then show whatever you will show with the Data you now have.

As a plus, since your download is a background process, you could use the Observer Pattern (Listener Pattern) where your Activity will implement a let's say `AsyncTaskListener` interface where `AsyncTask` is the name of the class of your download background process, this interface should have the methods that the Activity will call on the background process, let's say a method like `cancelProgressDialog()` that will be called in the `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask` class, the last thing you need to do is create an instance variable (member) of the interface in your AsyncTask class and maybe by the `Constructor` or a `Setter` method set the interface to it.
Here is an Example:

Interface:

```
public interface MessageHandlerListener {
public void toastMessage(int messageId);
}
```

Activity:

```
public class AnyActivityThatNeedsToShowAMessageInABackgroundProcessOrInUIThread extends Activity implements MessageHandlerListener {
    public void toastMessage(int messageId){
        //show a toast implementation
}
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class BackgroundProcess extends AsyncTask {
    MessageHandlerListener mMessageHandlerListener;

public BackgroundProcess(MessageHandlerListener m){
    mMessageHandlerListener = m;
}

 protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects){
    return null
}

 protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
   mMessageHandlerListener.toastMessage(Message.CONSTANT_MESSAGE);
}
}
```

This is a way better aproach and let you apply the MVC pattern in android where your background process could be the Controller, your Activity(s) the View and have a good Model depending on the needs of the project. Regards.

Comment: Your English is great! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome, and check the code i modify something that wasn't ok :)